# Android Browser Extensions

Tags: android, browser

Is it possible to write "extensions" for the webkit based browser found on Android devices?

i.e. extensions akin to Google Chrome's ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not via the Android SDK at this time. As a part of Android firmware, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Not in the familiar way of writing desktop browser extensions. However, you do have access to things like bookmarks.  [Steven Van Bael](http://www.vbsteven.be/blog/how-and-why-i-wrote-bookmark-to-desktop-for-android-in-2-days/) has demonstrated that.